# PyUSBが最初からコンパイルエラーです　no module named ’usb’

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb

Raspberry PiにUSB機器(センサ)を接続し、PyUSBを使ってデータを通信したいと思います。プログラム言語はPythonです。
さて、pyusb,libusbもインストール済ですが、最初から以下のコンパイルエラーがでます。

```
no module named 'usb'
```

USB機器はlsusbで確認するとベンダID、プロダクトIDも出てきます。エラーが出るのはどのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
```

Comment: 念のため、それぞれどのような手順でモジュールをインストールしたかも質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: 参考: [Installed pyusb, still: 'ImportError: no module named core'](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6774)

Comment: ありがとうございました。リンク先のコメントを見て、python3-usbとpython-usbをインストールして実行したところ、「import」の箇所は無事通過したようです。お恥ずかしい話ですが、ソースコードのその数行後の箇所で別のエラーが出ました。これは別件と考え、後日、ソース全体を表示してまた質問させていただく場合もあるかもしれません。その際はよろしくお願いいたします。とりあえず、「no module named 'usb'」の件は解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ヒントになったようでなりよりです。私自身は Python に詳しくないのでコメントに留めましたが、今回あなたが実際に試して解決に至った手順を **自己回答** の形で投稿してもらえると、同じような問題で困った人の助けになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

pyusbモジュールが導入されていないのだと思います。

`pip install pyusb` 
ちなみに私の環境では以下の通りでした。

```
C:\Users>python
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import usb.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb'　★そんなモジュールないというエラー
>>> quit()

C:\Users>pip install pyusb　モジュールを導入
Collecting pyusb
  Downloading pyusb-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 4.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyusb
Successfully installed pyusb-1.1.1

C:\Users>python
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import usb.core　★はい完了
>>>
```